# Executing 2 scripts based on different variables

Tags: php, sql, variables, require-once

I have an Sql database which has a table containing: Email, Company, Name.  When I do a query on that database and compare E-mail addresses I also get `trim($row['company'])` & `trim($row['name'])` so that the Company and Name of the person associated with that Email address are also brought down.

My problem is this:  I am using require_once based on the `trim($row['company'])` & `trim($row['name'])` that is associated with the E-mail address.  Ex.

```
require_once "/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/" . trim($row['company']) . "/Users/" . trim($row['name']) . "/example.php";
```

So using the above example, the script is then pointed to the example.php script located in the directory using the company and name variables that it got from the database, based on the email.

If I have 2 emails say each are from the same company so trim($row['company']) would stay the same, but the 2 emails are assigned to different users, so trim($row['name']) would be different.  Is there a way that when I use require_once that I can have both example.php scripts in both directories executed?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use require_once, but only require (or include if you feel better).

Comment: You should justify this sentance, because it doesn't add any value to just say: do X

Answer (score 0):

### This looks unsafe

This looks unsafe if you don't do proper escaping, as user could input arbitrary characters and harm your script. (i.e. lead to another script like when inputting name "../AnotherUser")

### The answer

But yes, you can include all scripts for particular company by using [glob](http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to enumerate all directories under specific directory:

```
foreach(glob("/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/" . trim($row['company']) . "/Users/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $userDir) {
    require_once($userDir."/example.php");
}
```

Comment: The user can't possibly input another user name.  That data is stored in the database when they register, so once they register with their email, name, and company, they can't possibly get to another user directory.

Comment: What I have is this.  I have a script that is checking my inbox for unread e-mails.  If there are unread e-mails it will look at the e-mail address it came from (Will come from different people, different companies, etc etc) and will then take the attachment from that e-mail and place it it their directory based on the company name, and the user name associated with that email address in the database.  If I have 2 unread emails from 2 different "users" in the same company, how do I execute both of there example.php scripts?

Comment: If you don't validate the value that is being stored in database, then there IS a security issue.

And why can't you execute your script once for each unread email?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you need to retrieve more than 1 row from your database.  So you would have an array of arrays as your result.  For example:

```
$result = array(
   0 => array('email' => 'alex@abc.com', 'name' => 'Alex', 'company' => 'ABC'),
   1 => array('email' => 'beth@xyz.com', 'name' => 'Beth', 'company' => 'XYZ')
);
```

Once you retrieve the data like that you would use the following code to run the script for each of them:

```
foreach ($result as $row)
{
   require('/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/' . trim($row['company']) . '/Users/' . trim($row['name']) . '/example.php');
}
```

As far as how to retrieve multiple rows for all the emails from your database that depends on your DB code so I can't really help there without seeing what you use.